# TextFormField throws an exception on startUp and when the keyboard keys are pressed

Tags: android, flutter, input, mobile

I have a TextFormField in my code where the user needs to enter a word (in this case an email)
but when the application opens this screen it immediately throws an exception and that exception is repeated everytime the user presses the keys on the keyboard

```
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.app.trust.ITrustManager.isDeviceLocked(int)' on a null object reference
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1626)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591):    at android.content.IClipboard$Stub$Proxy.hasPrimaryClip(IClipboard.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591):    at android.content.ClipboardManager.hasPrimaryClip(ClipboardManager.java:156)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:287)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.access$700(PlatformPlugin.java:26)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin$1.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformChannel.java:141)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:693)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5445)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(24591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This is the exception that is called, I believe it's because of the TextFormField, because when I  comment the code related to that Widget, the exception disappears.

My code for this Widget:

```
class AuthPageState extends State<AuthPage> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _email, _password = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final emailField = SizedBox(
      height: 44.0,
      child: TextFormField(
          obscureText: false,
          onChanged: (val) => _email = val,
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
            labelText: "Email",
            hintText: "Enter Valid Email",
            border:
                OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
          )),
    );
  return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Form(key: formKey, child: emailField),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Maybe I've added something in the wrong place or I am forgetting something. I'm fairly new to mobile development in Flutter. I don't understand this exception, and so far I haven't found any information about this type of exceptions with TextFormField.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The error is about a method 'isDeviceLocked' called on a non initialised object... Which seems not to be related to your form.
Can you try to remove `Form(key: formKey, child: emailField),` to see if it's related to the emailField ?

Comment: When I comment the Form line the exception disappears. 
I also tried commenting the emaiField and it also disappears. 
The moment I uncomment the emailField the exception appears. :/

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,` is deprecated, try to remove it [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField/TextFormField.html)

Comment: Wasn't the autovalidate parameter that got deprecated?
And the autovalidateMode replaced it?
https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/form-field-autovalidation-api#description-of-change

But even if I comment on that line/parameter the same error still occurs, this exception be damned.

Comment: Indeed, my bad ! What happen when you put your SizedBox code inside the Form ? To replace the emailField  ? And what if you remove the SizeBox, and use directly the TextFormField ?

Comment: It's ok, thank you for your help so far! 
So far nothing seemed to change, I even deleted everything insideTextFormField () leaving it as an empty Widget, and the exception still appeared. 
If I comment the Widget the exception is never shown.

Comment: Did you try to start from scratch with this example : https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation ?

Comment: Uh, it also gives the same error. In theory, this should have worked correctly.
Could this be from my Flutter SDK (?) Perhaps?
In my pubspec I have  ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0", not sure if this info helps.

Comment: No it's the common version, it's ok. Are you sure it cannot comes from another piece of code ? Because your error is about a isDeviceLocked method, are you looking at some point at the state of the device ? (locked or not)